# Connection to rabbitmq failed when deploying spring cloud data flow in the local

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I referenced the documentation: https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/manual/ to run the spring cloud data flow in my local mac, and then deployed an `http | log` stream according to https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/getting-started/stream/.

But during the "verifying output (local)" step (https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/getting-started/stream/#local), I failed.

I can see there are a lot of connection error in the log:

[image]

### Summary, the steps I took:

- In terminal 1, start rabbitmq by `docker run -d --hostname rabbitmq --name rabbitmq -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3.7`
- Then in terminal 1, start skipper server by `java -jar spring-cloud-skipper-server-2.9.2.jar`[image]
- Then in terminal 2, start dataflow server by `java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.10.2.jar`[image]
- Then in terminal 3, start dataflow shell by `java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-shell-2.10.2.jar`[image]
- Open http://localhost:9393/dashboard/index.html#/streams/list/http-ingest dashboard to create stream and deploy
- Then in terminal 4, send `curl http://localhost:20100 -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "Happy streaming"`. The request was successfully sent, but no response body.

### Additional information

I can get success response from localhost:20100 like:
[image]

The docker containers are as follows:
[image]

### Expected (Help wanted!)

I can verify the output as suggested by the documentation.

[image]

### Actual result:

But I didn't get the log. Instead, I get the following:

```
2023-08-09 03:25:47.057  INFO [http-source,2aa0ce95298cd6b1,db9808ed2bfa4443] 1 --- [oundedElastic-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2023-08-09 03:26:47.705 ERROR [http-source,2aa0ce95298cd6b1,f116c3c77334209a] 1 --- [oundedElastic-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@7a71c2e3]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[15], headers={content-length=15, http_requestMethod=POST, b3=2aa0ce95298cd6b1-db9808ed2bfa4443-0, nativeHeaders={}, host=localhost:20100, http_requestUrl=http://localhost:20100/, id=1bd16f86-c76a-fb4c-4362-6df88325daf7, contentType=text/plain, user-agent=curl/7.82.0, accept=*/*, timestamp=1691551546926}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.doSend(AbstractMessageRouter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.onNext(AbstractMessageHandler.java:88)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.onNext(AbstractMessageHandler.java:37)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.ReactiveStreamsConsumer$SubscriberDecorator.hookOnNext(ReactiveStreamsConsumer.java:296)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.ReactiveStreamsConsumer$SubscriberDecorator.hookOnNext(ReactiveStreamsConsumer.java:277)
    at reactor.core.publisher.BaseSubscriber.onNext(BaseSubscriber.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRefCount$RefCountInner.onNext(FluxRefCount.java:200)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish$PublishSubscriber.drain(FluxPublish.java:477)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish$PublishSubscriber.onNext(FluxPublish.java:268)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onNext(FluxDoFinally.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491)
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.tryEmitMessage(FluxMessageChannel.java:82)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.doSend(FluxMessageChannel.java:71)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.lambda$subscribeTo$5(FluxMessageChannel.java:123)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:196)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:440)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:527)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ReactorSleuth.lambda$null$6(ReactorSleuth.java:324)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:249)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2173)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2146)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.doRabbitSend(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:250)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.send(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.handleRequestMessage(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:180)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1223)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectAddresses(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:640)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:615)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:565)
    ... 53 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by connecting to the rabbitmq using host IP as it's run by docker.

But I followed the documentation to run it using docker, which lead to connection issues. I think the official document should be updated.
[image]

To get host IP, for mac osx you can use

```
ipconfig getifaddr en0
192.168.1.10
```

And then configure it into the apps during deploying stream step.

```
app.http.spring.rabbitmq.host=192.168.1.10
app.log.spring.rabbitmq.host=192.168.1.10
```